# recreate a LINQ to Entities query in DBO

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

In VS2015 using C#

I have a LINQ query that is taking way too long, until I can fix that I need to move forward.
I have a query that is returning a lot of records, then I am using other Linq queries against that returned data to work off of, like so:

```
 var Stops = (from stops in rDb.DistributionStopInformations
                     join line in rDb.DistributionLineItems on stops.UniqueIdNo equals line.UniqueIdNo
                     where line.DatetimeCreated > dateToCheck && stops.CustomerNo == TNGCustNo
                     select new
                     {
                         stops.UniqueIdNo,
                         stops.StopName,
                         stops.StopAddress,
                         stops.RouteCode,
                         stops.CustomerReference,
                         line.DatetimeCreated,
                         line.RmaNumber
                     }
             ).ToArray();
        int stopsCount = Stops.Count();

        var RMA_stops = (from rma in Stops where rma.RmaNumber != null select rma).ToArray();
```

I can then use RMA_stops (along with numerous others) without having to go back to the database over and over.

This works fine, but the Stops query is taking anywhere from a minute to over 5 minutes to run and that just is not working out.

I have basicly recreated the Stops query in ADO and it runs in about a second which is fine -- but my knowledge of ADO is embarrassingly poor...how can I convert the output from below to something that I can run Linq queries against, using their fields (strongly typed?)

```
 string mySelectQuery = "select distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no, stop_name, stop_address, route_code, customer_reference,"+
            "distribution_line_items.datetime_created, rma_number from distribution_stop_information join distribution_line_items on " +
            "distribution_line_items.unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no " +
            "where distribution_line_items.datetime_created > '2/22/2017' and customer_no = '91000'";

        PgSqlConnection pgConnection = new PgSqlConnection(myConnection);
        PgSqlCommand pgCommand = new PgSqlCommand(mySelectQuery, pgConnection);
        pgConnection.Open();
        PgSqlDataReader pgReader = pgCommand.ExecuteReader();

        //steps through it just to verify that the data is in fact coming back
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (pgReader.Read())
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + " " + pgReader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) for performance critical queries? It extends `IDbConnection` interface with `Query<T>` function which returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Taking raw SQL path would create more troubles than using L2E. Moreover the L2E query is quite simple in order to need raw SQL optimization. From what I see, the only difference is that the L2E will use SQL parameters while your hand written SQL query contains embedded constant values. Most likely the difference if coming from that - why don't you try your LINQ query with constants and see if that's the case. It would be much easier to make LINQ bind constants than materializing the raw SQL (for instance, can't use anonymous type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class that your reader can write to, kind of like you are doing in your LINQ query.

**sample code (not tested)**

```
public SomeClass
{
  public string UniqueIdNo {get;set;}
  public string RmaNumber {get;set;}
}

var data = new List<SomeClass>();
while (pgReader.Read())
{
  var someClass = new SomeClass();
  someClass.UniqueIdNo = pgReader.GetString(0);
  someClass.RmaNumber = pgReader.GetString(1);
  data.Add(someClass);
}
```

Even better if you use a micro orm like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) which will handle executing the sql and mapping the result to your object.

**sample code (not tested)**

```
using (var pgConnection = new PgSqlConnection(myConnection))
{
    pgConnection.Open();
    var mySelectQuery = "YOUR QUERY HERE";
    var results = pgConnection.Query<SomeClass>(mySelectQuery);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, and thanks for the Dapper link, never used it before.  Slick.